# Using refs and populate in a express API

Tags: mongodb, express

I'm trying to build the API to get all the users **Messages** using Express and MongoDB, the schema look like this:

```
mongoose.model(
    "Messages",
    new mongoose.Schema({
        Creatore: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Users" },
        title: { type: String, required: true },
        text: { type: String, required: true },
        CreatedDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    })
);
```

In the Express Server
**Add new message API :**

```
router.post("/AddMessage",  async (req, res, next) => {
    let { title, text } = req.body;
    if (!title || !text) {
        return res.status(409).json({ message: "Missing Data" });
    }
    let newMessage = new Messages({
        Creatore: req.session.userId, //this does not work
        title: title,
        text: text,
        CreatedDate: new Date(),
    });
    try {
        await newMessage.save();
        res.send(200);
    } catch {
        res.send(409);
    }
});
```

The problem when this API is called it does not fill the **Creatore** field.
I got this in the DataBase:

> _id: "654531b57c89295a96ace0aa"
> title: "Message"
> text: "Message"
> CreatedDate: 2023-11-03T17:45:25.525+00:00
> __v: 0

Sessions are well configured

```
app.use(
    session({
        secret: "imad",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: store,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        },
    })
);
```

**Get Messages API :**:

```
router.get("/GetMessages", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const messages = await Messages.find({}).populate('Creatore');
        res.json(messages);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to fetch messages" });
    }
});
```

And this does not populate the User in the Creatore Field

I expected when calling the Get Messages API the return a JSON that populate the owner of the Message in the Creatore field, I don't know if that because of the Express-session library if it does not allow me to pass the user id that is stoked in the session.
**Session Document Example:**

> _id: "ekhtIyX1jC9HAtQa45M9ZaAhdrOeA-dy"
> expires: 2023-11-04T17:32:45.862+00:00
> session:Object
> cookie:Object
> userId: "65452e9c97eaa2c238dfa6e1"

I tried really hard to find a solution for that problem. Any help please?

Comment: Can you confirm if your `app.use(session())` middleware is used **above** your route middleware? Secondly, inside your `router.post("/AddMessage"` route can you `console.log(req.session.userId)`. Thank you.

Comment: In the schema you declare `Creatore` as an ObjectId, but `req.session.userId` is probably a string.  Try casting or converting that string to an ObjectId

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/AddMessage", {
  method: "POST",
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(values),
});
```

I should allow the credentials, it is a really important step when developing, allowing the cookies to pass through the request into your server.